Azure B2C: add output claims for local sign in
I have a custom policy running in B2C.  Most of our users are local to B2C, but we also have our company's Entra ID tenant set up as an identity provider via OpenID Connect.
I need to be able to return an email claims well as an emails claim that contains the otherMails string collection.  I have both working for our OpenID Connect IDP, but I can't figure out how or where to add the claim for local sign ins.
I've tried many different changes to the XML, but haven't hit upon the right answer.
Edit:  This is in response to Sridevi's comment.
This is what I have in my XML files now, but I've been working on it for a couple of days, and trying different things.
In TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml, I have this:
<BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsTransformations>
    <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateOtherMailsFromSignInEmail" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" TransformationClaimType="item" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>
  </ClaimsTransformations>
</BuildingBlocks>

My RelayingParty section in SignUpOrSignin.xml looks like this:
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="CustomSignUpOrSignIn" />
    <Endpoints>
      <!--points to refresh token journey when app makes refresh token request-->
      <Endpoint Id="Token" UserJourneyReferenceId="RedeemRefreshToken" />
    </Endpoints>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateOtherMailsfromEmail" />
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateOtherMailsfromSignInEmail" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>      
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" PartnerClaimType="emails" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>

I have no idea if this is the right way to do it, if the code should be somewhere else, etc.

Please edit your question with more details by including your current code, configuration or debugging details

I got this to work.  I don't know if this was the best way to do it, but I made a new claims provider, set up a new technical profile, and set up the transformations as output claims transformations.
